# Is there a written Aghori/Aghor Shastra or are teachings based purely on guru-shishya transmission?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, shakti, shaktism

If there are shastra that are specific to Aghora can you please name it or them? I know Aghoris have their own mantras but I don't know if they are written down and based purely on memory.

Comment: Why do you want to leave the site? If you want to stop or change something in the site then it's possible only if if you stay. It's not possible if you delete your account.

Comment: I was not able to ask any question. Thanks for your support @Rickross I hope they don't start attacking you now because you are showing sympathy for me. I have now cancelled deletion......... Regarding Aghori did you come to know if we can get siddhi by stuti mantras like Om Mangla Kali Bhadra Kali Kapalini? I can't find this information anywhere.

Comment: Thanks that's a good decision. You were not able to ask any questions because you have asked many questions that were downvoted. System automatically puts an asking ban in such cases. I will surely look for answer to your question about that mantra

Comment: Kapalika/Skull and Tantra related questions like about preta or swapneshwari devi were downvoted and closed.... and thanks!! I find Kamakhya stuti is extremely powerful... more than most mantras I have seen

Comment: Okay .. I too have a book called Kamakhya Tantram.

Comment: People here are not that knowledgeable. They must be hearing from you about Swapnewsari Devi for the first time. Same about the importance of using the skull. Some may find it taboo too. So, don't be bothered about such closures.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks a lot! :) I'm not an initiated Tantrik so don't know about Kamakhya tantram... I only knew that Kali is called Kamakhya in Kalika Puraan and I know that part of (or complete) Kamakhya stuti is from Markandeya Puraan. Hopefully I can find the book online !! And you're right they are ignorant like most people and their gurus have probably brainwashed them against Tantra

Comment: Aghoris follows a philosophy that is very close to Advaita Vedanta. They are an emergent sect from Natha sampradayas so they follow the yoga texts of dattatreya, adi nath, matsendranath, gorakhnath, etc. along with their own practices that are confined to them (as with any other sampradaya).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Aghoris have their own set of shastras along with guru sishya transmission system. Bhavishya Purana Pratisarga Parva Khanda 4 Adhyaya 13 shloka 19-20 states:

कपालमोचनात्कुण्डात्समागम्य महोतले।
यतिरूपो वेदनिधिभैरवो नाभ विश्रुतः।। अघोरं कठिनं मार्ग स्वशिष्यान्सभचोदय शङ्कराचार्यमागम्य शिष्योभूत्वा स गैरवः।
डामरं नात्र वै तन्त्रं मन्त्रभूतं चकार ह ।। कीलिता ये तु वै मन्त्रास्तेन चोत्कीलितीकृताः

The shloka means that Bhairava created a yati known as Vednidhi at Kapalamochana Ghat (Kashi) and that Vednidhi Yati composed the Damara tantras and trained his disciples in Aghormarg basically calling him the founder and the Tantras as their core text.

Aghoris also have sub branches from kapalikas who follow lakulagamas and the Nath sect's sub branch known as pav panth who follow Shabara tantras along with Kinaram parampara who follow a blend of shivayoga and Shabara tantras.